# String created from inputStream is not equal to its string literal

Tags: java, string

I'm constructing a String from a socket like this:

```
        StringBuilder bufferedStringInput = new StringBuilder(); 
        CharBuffer cbuf = CharBuffer.allocate(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);

        InputStream is = clientSocket.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        int noCharsLeft = 0;
        while(noCharsLeft != -1) {
            noCharsLeft = br.read(cbuf);
            bufferedStringInput.append(cbuf.toString());
            cbuf.clear();
        }
```

I then pass its `toString` value to a method to compare it to a string.
When I output the both they are exactly the same; in my case the string is "READ":

`System.out.println(inputString+READ)` gives me:  `READREAD`

I even tested to see what the difference between the Strings were using this implementation:http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0040__Data-Type/Getthedifferencebetweentwostrings.htm

It told me every substring (character) was different.

I'm confused.

Comment: How are you comparing the Strings?  == or .equals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one, your

```
while(noCharsLeft != -1) {
```

will loop once more than you want. It starts at `0`, so iterates, reads some chars (`noCharsLeft` is set to some positive value), and checks `while` again. It's still not `== -1` and so iterates again. This time it reads no characters into the buffer, but writes to the `StringBuilder`. You need to read once before checking the number of bytes read.

Second,

```
cbuf.toString()
```

returns a `String` starting at the current position in the buffer, which is one more than the last character added. That is, it contains `DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE - noCharsLeft` `'\0'` characters .

Ignoring encoding (which you shouldn't ignore, give a character encoding to your `InputStreamReader`), you'll want something like

```
while ((noCharsLeft = br.read(cbuf)) != -1) { 
    cbuf.rewind();
    bufferedStringInput.append(cbuf, 0, noCharsLeft);
    cbuf.clear();
}
```

Here, you read the first batch of characters. You then rewind your buffer to set the position at index 0. You then append `noCharsLeft` characters from the buffer to the `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Will give this a try. One moment.

Comment: @cbrad Can you explain _it still fails_? What is the length of the two strings? What is the size of `arr`? Is it equal to `noCharsLeft`? (This works for me.)

Comment: Edited my comment, jumped the gun too quick in my code. Let me make sure I have everything right on my end. Sorry about that.

Comment: Anddddd it works. Thanks very much Sotirios! Byte streams are new to me.

Comment: @cbrad Note that the `CharBuffer` isn't particularly useful here imo. You can just use a `char[]` directly.