# inputStream String is different from string literal

Tags: java, string, inputstream

After trying to compare the inputStream String to another String, no matter what I do (.equals, .compareTo), they aren't equal, even though they are.

```
String readString = "READ";
System.out.println(method + " =? " + readString);
if (method.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(readString)) {
    System.out.println("Is READ");
} else {
    System.out.println("Is not READ");
}
```

It prints out,

```
READ =? READ
Is not READ
```

even though the method variable is definitely READ.

Then I messaged one of my friends who was having the same problem, and he said it's because of the inputStream where I parsed the method variable.

```
BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(
        connectionSocket.getInputStream()
    ,   "UTF8"
    )
);
StringBuilder arrInput = new StringBuilder();
char[] cbuf = new char[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];
int bytesRead;

// Build client's input and parse it
while (true) {
    bytesRead = inFromClient.read(cbuf);

    arrInput.append(cbuf);
    ...
    // lots of parsing below and then a break
}
```

I've tried my friend's solution: [String created from inputStream is not equal to its string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26568461/string-created-from-inputstream-is-not-equal-to-its-string-literal)

But I ended up only getting part of the input I'm reading, unlike he did.

Comment: please put the code for what `method` is on the first chunk

Comment: You should only be appending `bytesRead` bytes from the `cbuf`.

Answer (score 4):

> even though the method variable is definitely READ.

Actually, it is **definitely not** `"READ"`.  If it was, then you would get different output.  The computer is NOT wrong.  The real issue here is that there is something about this that you do not understand.

(There is a lesson there ... which you would be wise to learn.)

There are two possible explanations for what you are seeing:

- There are "invisible" (aka "non-printing") characters in one of the strings you are trying to compare.  By calling `trim()` you are removing leading and trailing whitespace, but there are other invisible characters that `trim()` doesn't remove (e.g. ASCII NUL characters).
- There are characters that look like other ones ... but aren't.  Google for the search term "homoglyphs".

---

Indeed, looking at the code where you put characters into a `StringBuffer` (which presumably then gives you the `String` that you are testing ...), it is pretty clear that the problem is the first one.  You are creating a string from the entire character array ... not from the part of the array that you read characters into.  This line is incorrect:

```
arrInput.append(cbuf);
```

'cos you are ignoring the number of characters that were *actually* read.

Comment: Whoops, it's true that it is definitely not read if I am having this problem. Anyway, I parsed arrInput into multiple strings and then I compare them to a literal string. But when you said I'm not using the part of the array that I read characters into, do you mean cbuf? I'm actually using arrInput to parse.

Comment: Ah, I changed that line you mention to `arrInput.append(cbuf, 0, bytesRead);` But after doing that, I'm missing a lot of the input data. The data I'm trying to read has newlines (\r\n).

Comment: I can't tell you why that is happening, but it is *probably* in the code that you are not showing us.  Whatever, `append(cbuf)` is indisputably wrong.  Read the javadocs.